Error when trying to access on-device app files in Android Studio
I'm trying to access a SQLite table i have on my app through the Android studio File Explorer, but when opening the app/data/data I'm presented with a red error massage Error executing shell command pm list packages..
I'm using Android Studio Jellyfish 2023.3.1 RC 2
Thanks.
file explorer error
